# Symplectic quotient of projective variety is projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and $\mathfrak g^*$ be dual of Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Let $M$ be a compact projective variety and $G$ act on $M$ freely and $M$ is $G$ equivariant, and $\mu:M\to \mathfrak g^*$ be a moment map, then the symplectic quotient $M_\lambda$, $\lambda\in \mathfrak g^*$ is still projective?

Comment: If $M$ is compact then a Hamiltonian action of an non-trivial connected group cannot be free: $\mu$ must have critical points (certainly it may act freely \emph{on a level set} but this is different).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer is yes.

First note that the complexification $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $G$ is reductive and contains $G$ as a maximal compact subgroup. Secondly, $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ acts algebraically on $M$ via an extension of the original $G$-action. Your symplectic quotient is then homeomorphic to the projective Geometric Invariant Theory quotient of $M$ by $G_{\mathbb{C}}$.

A useful reference is Chapter 8 of Kirwan's thesis, Cohomology of Quotients in Symplectic and Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: But I think you must add the condition $M^s=M^{ss}$?

Comment: I don't believe this is necessary. I think you need only assume that the $G$-stabilizers are finite. However, you took care of this by requiring the $G$-action to be free.

Comment: Here has been written http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6316/when-are-git-quotients-projective?rq=1

Comment: A reference for the specific fact to which I'm referring is page 84 of http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/201096185821505.pdf

Comment: I can not see it in page 84

Comment: It is the first sentence in the second paragraph.

Comment: YES, ALSO IN END LINE OF PAGE 3 http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/kirwan.pdf WE HAVE IT

Comment: Do you now agree with what I have written?